# Сравнение переменной с данными из массива

Tags: python

Не могу понять, какие условия необходимо выполнить для сравнения переменной с данными из массива.

Ниже простенькая игра, в конце кода которой для сохранения правописания при выводе количества ходов необходимо вывести (шаг/шага/шагов). Что сделал не так?

```
from random import randint
zag = randint(1, 100)

a = 1
print("Угадай число от 1 до 100")


while (zag >= 0 and zag<= 100):
    print('шаг', a)
    otv = int(input("Ваш вариант?: "))
a = a+1

    if (otv < zag):
        print("                 Больше!")
    elif (otv > zag):
        print("                 Меньше!")
    else:
    break
c = [1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
d = [2,3,4,22,23,24,25,32,33,34,42,43,44,52,53,54,62,63,64,72,73,74,82,83,84,92,93,94]

if  (a == c):
    b = ('шаг')

elif (a == d):
    b = ('шага')

else:
    b = ('шагов')

print("Угадал! За", a, b)
```

Comment: переменную-число нельзя сравнивать со списком. Вам нужно проверить с помощью `in`. Однако задачу можно решить с помощью остатков от деления на 100 и на 10

Comment: Да, уже разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: Но обычным делением тут не обойтись, т.к. есть три варианта ответа и "уникальное" число (11) оно тоже относится к слову 'шагов'

Answer (score 2):

Вхождение в список можно проверить с помощью `in`, но все натуральные числа так не перечислить, поэтому для произвольного диапазона лучше сделать так:

```
def sklon(n, s1, s2, s5):
    if ((n%100)//10==1):  #...10..19
        return s5
    n10 = (n+9)%10    #объединяем 0 с диапазоном 5..9
    if n10==0:
        return s1
    elif n10<4:
        return s2
    else:
        return s5

for i in range(30):
    print(i, sklon(i, "шаг", "шага", "шагов"))
```

Comment: Выдает список целиком до 29 шага. Но обязательно разберусь и изучу. Спасибо!

Comment: `до 29 шага` ну да, я сделал это для демонстрации правильности работы функции

Answer (score 0):

Если вы тоже не знаете и ищете ответ, то вот ниже исправленный код:

```
from random import randint
zag = randint(1, 100)

a = 0

print (zag)
print("Угадай число от 1 до 100")


while (zag >= 0 and zag<= 100):
    print('шаг', a+1)
    otv = int(input("Ваш вариант?: "))
    a = a+1

    if (otv < zag):
        print("                 Больше!")
    elif (otv > zag):
        print("                 Меньше!")
    else:
        break
c = [1, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91]
d = [2,3,4,22,23,24,25,32,33,34,42,43,44,52,53,54,62,63,64,72,73,74,82,83,84,92,93,94]

if  a in c:
    b = ('шаг')

elif a in d:
    b = ('шага')

else:
    b = ('шагов')

print("Угадал! За", a, b)
```